# Python math: Create a new variable which is a figure minus a variable

Tags: python

I currently have some x and y coord data saved as two variables. I want to create a new variable which is a figure, minus these variables. E.G my current code looks like this.

```
x_coords_a = ([float((k['X'])) * 124.5 for k in data['a']])
y_coords_a = ([float((k['Y'])) * 80 for k in data['a']])
```

And this would be the calculation I would want performed:

newvariable = 120 minus x_coords_a

newvariable2 = 80 minus y_coords_a

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem you don't know how to tell Python to do subtraction?

Comment: What do you expect `newvariable` and `newvariable2` to contains when this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with a list we can use a [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) like so:

```
x_coords_a = [1.22,3.5564,12]
y_coords_a = [1.22,3.5564,12]

x_calc = [120-i for i in x_coords_a]
y_calc = [80-i for i in y_coords_a]
```

Comment: This worked a treat! Sorry I should have explained it better in my example that the output where in lists - but thanks very much!

Comment: No problem, I should have seen it there :) also for the future please read the article i linked, it shows how to add if and else statements and how to do it in dictonaries as well.

Comment: But glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the original values you can do:

```
x_coords_a = ([float((k['X'])) * 124.5 for k in data['a']])
y_coords_a = ([float((k['Y'])) * 80 for k in data['a']])

#after calculation:
x_coords_a = 120 - x_coords_a
y_coords_a = 80 - y_coords_a
```

if you need them just create new variables:

```
x_coords_a = ([float((k['X'])) * 124.5 for k in data['a']])
y_coords_a = ([float((k['Y'])) * 80 for k in data['a']])

x_coords_calc = 120 - x_coords_a
y_coords_calc = 80 - y_coords_a
```

or just do it in "one" line:

```
x_coords_a = 120 - ([float((k['X'])) * 124.5 for k in data['a']])
y_coords_a = 80 - ([float((k['Y'])) * 80 for k in data['a']])
```

Comment: if i didnt get your question please comment :)

Comment: Thanks Peter! Although I am getting a error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'" when trying these methods

Comment: could you please provide a input? or just what is the output when you print one of them

Comment: `x_coords_a` and `y_coords_a` are lists.

Comment: I assumed it was a float but if i see the list i can try to provide you with a list comprehention :)

Comment: like [1,12,12313,5445645]? or does it contain the float values as strings?